# Splitting unrecognized timestamp column into separate date and time columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a problem splitting column name timedate and I want to split it into time and column date.

```
TimeDate
00:00:00 (01/01/2018)
01:00:00 (01/01/2018)
02:00:00 (01/01/2018)
```

I tried using pandas datetime method but it won't work

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Time / Date."]).dt.date
```

Got this error

```
('Unknown string format:', '00:00:00 (01/01/2018)')
```

Any idea how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just pass the format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TimeDate'], format='%H:%M:%S (%m/%d/%Y)').dt.date
```

Output:

```
0    2018-01-01
1    2018-01-01
2    2018-01-01
Name: TimeDate, dtype: object
```